# today() function in Google Sheets returns 1/1/1970 regardless of the input

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

Here is my simple example
[toDate() function in Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GUZB9eTlM6hBAtapWzTPrFotkKmG-M0zzTrpnMyUVVE/edit?usp=sharing)

I am trying to use todate() function in a query and it returns 1/1/1970, instead of a date. The documentation for todate() says that "Given a date, it returns the same value.".
What is w

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your example is technically working, just not as you expect.

Try temporarily changing your query from `select todate(Col1)` to `select Col1` and observe that it produces a bunch of large numbers as a result. According to the documentation you link, the todate() function then treats that as seconds since Jan 1, 1970. Since the seconds are all under 1 day's worth, it looks like you are just getting 1/1/1970 over and over again.

Hopefully that is helpful to you. The query function is new to me, so I'm not able to help much more than that.

Comment: function. today() function is documented here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage . The column B is computed as a function =query(arrayformula(if({1,0}, A2:A, A2:A)),"select todate(Col1) ") and I can not use to_date() (with underscore) inside the query().

Comment: I see, I missed the fact that you were using the query function. Please see my updated answer, it might contain useful information for you.